# Fetching a cluster / group of values from a Database Table - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, oracle11g

[image: Table to fetch data from]

The problem here is I have a table. This table consist of some purchase orders made over years. Corresponding to these purchase orders you can see these Sales Orders lined up also. All I want is to fetch those Purchase Orders which have more that one Sales Order.

Comment: It is completely unclear how your datastructure is from this description. Describe the existing tables and the relevant foreign and primary key constraints.

Comment: sure thing. actually i am trying to post screens but there is some problem. i will do the nedful and provide you the meta data.

Comment: It's highly preferable to post text instead of screenshots.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: sorry for the mess. will try and keep things a bit tidy next time.
still thanks for considering.

Comment: -a_horse_with_no_name

great help.

would keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `vc_po_no` signifies a **p**ayment **o**rder and `vc_so_no` signifies a **s**ales **o**rder, you could group by `vc_po_no` and count the number of `vc_so_no`s:

```
SELECT   vc_po_no
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY vc_po_no
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT vc_so_no) >= 2
```

Comment: Mureinik

thanks a lot. seeing you solution, I feel a bit stupid to have asked such a puny query. Really, where is my mind!

Still thanks a lot.